# KeyError Post DjangoRestFramework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm new on Django Rest Framework and when I want to POST data I get a error: **KeyError: 'id_area'** I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

in my models.py

```
class Area(models.Model):
id_area = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
APM = 'apm'
BUSINESS = 'business'
DESARROLLO = 'desarrollo'
SISTEMAS = 'sistemas'

ATENTUSIANOS_CHOICES = (
    (APM, 'Apm'),
    (BUSINESS, 'Business'),
    (DESARROLLO, 'Desarrollo'),
    (SISTEMAS, 'Sistemas'),
)

nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=ATENTUSIANOS_CHOICES)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Área'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Áreas'

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre

class Atentusiano(models.Model):
id_atentusiano = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
apellido = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
correo = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
anexo = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
area = models.ForeignKey(Area, related_name='areas', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Atentusiano'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Atentusianos'
    ordering = ['nombre']

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre + ' ' + self.apellido
```

in my serializers.py

```
class AreaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
areas = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = Area
    fields = ('id_area', 'nombre', 'areas')

class AtentusianoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
atentusianos = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
area = serializers.CharField(source='area.nombre', read_only=True)
id_area = serializers.CharField(source='area.id_area')

class Meta:
    model = Atentusiano
    fields = ['id_atentusiano', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'correo', 'anexo', 'id_area', 'area', 'atentusianos']

def create(self, validated_data):
    area_data = validated_data.pop('id_area')
    area = models.Area.objects.create(**area_data)
    atentusiano = models.Atentusiano.objects.create(area=area, **validated_data)
    return atentusiano
```

And in my views.py

```
class AtentusianoView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Atentusiano.objects.all()
serializer_class = AtentusianoSerializer

class AreaView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Area.objects.all()
serializer_class = AreaSerializer
```

The problem is that when I want to Post data, for example:
{
    "nombre": "name",
    "apellido": "lastname",
    "correo": "email@gmail.com",
    "anexo": "1364",
    "id_area": "1"
}

i got this error **area_data = validated_data.pop('id_area')
KeyError: 'id_area'**

I need help please

Comment: Are you trying to post JSON data or FormData?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should `pop` like this,

```
class AtentusianoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    .....
    .....

class Meta:
    model = Atentusiano
    fields = ['id_atentusiano', 'nombre', 'apellido', 'correo', 'anexo', 'id_area', 'area', 'atentusianos']

def create(self, validated_data):
    id_area = validated_data.pop('area')['id_area'] # here the correction
    area = Area.objects.create(id_area=id_area) # an additional correction
    atentusiano = Atentusiano.objects.create(area=area, **validated_data)
    return atentusiano
```

**EDIT**: As `id_area` value, you are passing a `string` instead of an `integer` which will through another error. Also not,

`area = models.Area.objects.create(**area_data)`

it should be,

`area = Area.objects.create(id_area=id_area)`